# We've got a competitor

Tags: discussion

Looks like we've got a competitor, and one rather well established: http://russianlearn.com/forums

*russianlearn.com* site seems to be a general resource for those learning Russian language, history, etc., and the forum section has individual forums on various topics: grammar, syntax, literature, culture, history, cooking, and so.

While it may be great if we could sneak an advertisement for our forum in there, I'm afraid, it won't be easy.

Comment: I don't think we're really competitors. That's a forum, we're a Q&A. They talk about anything related to Russia, we talk about the language only. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, we have many competitors, and the most serious on, in my opinion, is the WordReference Russian forum.

Our advantage is that RL&U has better format for question answering.
Their advantage is that they allow discussions, and it must be a better place to be for people that go not only for the information, but also for social thing.

Maybe, we should think how can we make our place more interesting, just a fun place to hang out?

Comment: SE is social as well, you can go chat, or flame in comments... :)

Answer (score 0):

We could register there and participate as usual, once in a while answering questions with "oh, of course, it had been discussed on RLU.SE ages ago, see here!".

However this site: http://lingvoforum.net/index.php/board,106.0.html is a much more authoritative resource in my opinion.

Comment: I don't know maybe the [topic](http://lingvoforum.net/index.php/topic,50250.0.html) I randomly chose was not the best one but I did not get that feeling of "authoritativeness". The user interface of SE is more convenient though: f.e. there are reputations and history of questions for all users. There are no commercials here (yet). We can attach several tags to a questions but there you can put it in only one section.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small warning. There exists a Russian version of Stack Exchange called  [Сеть знаний](http://sezn.ru) .  I discovered it thanks to [Hash Code](http://hashcode.ru) a bit later than Stack Overflow (cause I really needed a solution to one programming problem ). It has the same design and the same structure as SE, with minor differences. I wonder how it is possible, because they are owned by different companies as far as I know.

Anyway, what **Сеть Знаний** doesn't have is **Area 51** (to create a site you must write to owners). Besides, although I have an account there, I have stopped 
 visiting this site: there is way too high percent of impolite posts/comments and often, instead of helping each other, people tend to try to show how clever they are...

So, the real competitor could be [Русский Язык](http://russ.hashcode.ru).

Comment: SE and СЗ either work off the same Q&A software, or the latter uses one of the [myriad clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953).

Comment: @theUg, thanks for an explanation of this strange coincidence =) I'll read more about clones.